# Detect if number is factorial recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, recursion, factorial

Need to create a function to evaluate if a specific number is factorial, or not.

For that I've built the following, and it is working

```
def is_factorial(n):
    i = f = 1
    while f < n:
        i += 1
        f *= i
    return f == n
```

However, now I need to make it recursive, but I am struggling with it.

So far I've managed to do the following

```
def isFactorial(m):
    def factorial(x):
        if x == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return x * factorial(x - 1)
    
    if m == 1:
        return True 
    elif m == 720:
        return True
    else:
        factorialnumbers = []
```

Appreciate any help.

**Edit**: Apologies, but I forgot to specify that the function should take as input one integer only.

Comment: Does https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/279004/general-way-to-convert-a-loop-while-for-to-recursion-or-from-a-recursion-to-a help?

Comment: Why do you want to make it recursive. it is perfectly fine and some what efficient? If you have a great number of tests, you may build a table of factorials up to the max of the values to be tested.

Comment: Aside from mechanically converting the loop to recursion, there's no "nice" recursive version of this problem like there is for `factorial` itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def is_factorial(n, i=1):
    n = n/i
    if n == 1:
        return True
    if n < 1:
        return False
    i += 1
    return is_factorial(n, i)


print(is_factorial(24))
```

Comment: This isn't guaranteed to work. `n/i` could be arbitrarily close to 1 without *equaling* 1, so floating-point imprecision will give you a false positive.

Comment: Should use n = n // i to avoid float issue that chepner points out.

Comment: If `n/i` is very close to `1`, then the tested number was almost factorial. To demonstrate try `is_factorial(24-10e-8)` and `is_factorial(24-10e-16)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
def isfact(m,n):
  def fact(n):
      if n==1 or n==0:
          return 1
      else:
          return n*fact(n-1)
  if fact(n) == m:
      return True
  else:
      return False
```